# Modify a page to remove invalid Javascript prior to it being parsed

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer, proxy

To provide some background, I'm working with a CMS which I don't have much control over. I wanted to add google analytics so I injected some Javascript into the page as a normal html link. Which I thought was really clever of me until I realised that broke the whole CMS in the process.

In order to remove the Javscript I need to be able to use the CMS. I don't have DB access.

What I want to do is using either a proxy or some kind of clever browser addon, essentially do a simple string replace on the page to remove the bad code. And, just to make things more interesting, the CMS requires ActiveX which limits me to using IE.

Any suggestions or advice on either how to set up a local proxy to do this or otherwise use a browser addon to make the page work would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Just to be clear, I am quite confident that the injected code is causing a Javascript error.

Comment: So what you want to do is edit it somehow with a browser add on so you can access it in the CMS? And what CMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Firebug.

Load up the page, then right click on the link you modified and choose "inspect element", then you can edit the html, or javascript right there.

Oh, and don't use IE, use Firefox. Chrome actually some some built in debugging tools you can use as well.

Comment: He has to be able to edit it and save not just edit it for that time. (I think) So that wont work as he has to be able to actually edit it to fix it through the CMS. Once you refresh the page everything you did in the Dev. Tools will be gone. And he said he has to use IE, unfortunately, because it requires ActiveX.

Comment: My understanding is he just needs it to work long enough to remove the javascript. You remove the bad javascript, then use the website to edit and save the page. I missed the ActiveX part.

Comment: An idea for the ActiveX: I bet the site doesn't actually need ActiveX for all of it, just parts. So you fake it. You change the browser user agent to IE, and hope it loads. Then you use the javascript part of the site to edit the CMS.

Comment: Googling for "IE debug" came up with lots of stuff.

Comment: He said the CMS requires ActiveX (never heard of a CMS that requires that)